# KO 3.2 - need advice about ajax design

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation, kohana

I'm using ajax to call a controller through kohana routing. Inside of this controller I validate all fields of my form, and save data about fields which have failed validation to an attribute.

The next thing I wanna do is to make the second ajax call to the same controller, retrieve this attribute, and do some actions with this.

However, in the second call, the attribute is obviously empty.

Is there a way to solve this? Without echoing the attribute in the first ajax call?

EDIT.

```
$("#form").validate({
   rules {
      remote: "ajax_file.php"
   }
   messages {
      // I want to get information from ajax call above here
   }
});
```

jQuery: 1.9.0

In the first block(rules) I have to echo TRUE or FALSE - that's why I can't echo also info about failed fields.

In the ajax_file.php I'm gathering data about failed fields, and I have to make second ajax call below (messages) and work on this data in the second .php file.

Comment: What's wrong with echoing the attribute in the first ajax call? You'd skip one step and speed up the application this way. Any particular reasons why you don't want to do this?

Comment: Also, we are not able to tell you what's wrong without seeing what's wrong. Nobody here is going to guess how your application looks like, so I suggest you provide us with some code.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I edited and better described my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood, you want to validate a fields, correct? Why don't you validate the fields in yours Controller by using kohana class 'Validate' (Validate::factory($_POST)) with any rules you wish... And then return the result to the form.

PS In your case, you can execute a second ajax call after the first call is finished, using ajax success option

Answer (score 0):

Avoid making two requests...you can do it under one request instead..

in your controller

```
public function action_ajaxmethod(){

  // do some validation code here
  // every error will be stored in
  // **err** variable

  if(!empty(err)) die(json_encode("success" => false, "errors" => err));
  else die(json_encode("success" => true));
}
```

in your js

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajaxmethod',
  data: {data: data},
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result){
    if(result['success']==true){
      // do some actions
    }
    else{
      // do some actions
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps...